# invalid left hand assignment javascript

Tags: javascript

So I am coding a bot script in javascript for a CS:GO betting website and i'm getting an invalid left hand assignment any help?

```
if(lastRollColor !== lastBetColor && 0=0){
     betColor = 'black';
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Just a wild guess, but maybe the problem is an invalid left-hand assignment?

Answer (score 1):

`0=0` is an assignment. You cannot assign to a constant value.

What you probably want is `0==0`. You could just change that to `true`... and then remove it entirely, because it wouldn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

`0=0` is an assignment. You can not assign to `0`.

`0==0` is a comparison.

But anyway, the condition `0==0` is usually a leftover from debugging,
e.g. you replace it with `0==1` to "disable" a condition.